# While loop without explicit increment / counter (basic)

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements, increment

I am new to php and it's my first language. So my question seems to be very basic.

First the basic concept of a while loop seems pretty clear to me. 
As long as i increment (i++) until the "crash condition" (i<10) becomes true.

But I realy wonder why the following code example without any explicit incrementation works.

```
$originals = "originale";
$thumbnails="thumbnails";
$directory = opendir($originale);
$images = array();
while(($file = readdir($directory)) !== false) {
    if(preg_match("/\.jp?g$/i", $file)){
        $images[] = $file;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($images);
echo "</pre>";
closedir($directory);
```

Obviously I missed something. It seems to be magic. I would expect an enless loop which returns the first file... ?

I hope that despite my English (sorry for that) the question becomes clear.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `while`-loops run *while* the condition inside their braces is true. the condition in this case is `($file = readdir($directory))`, which tries to assign a new filename from the directory to $file and - as a whole - returns false if there is no new file available. **but:** explanation of basic code is quite off-topic for SO - this is not a tutorial site. [search engine of your choice] provides quite a few which should be better suited for your needs.

Comment: Because while loop's doesn't need to have a incremental value, as long as there is _something_ to break the loop, in this case it's when `$file` is set to false.

Comment: readdir will advance the pointer, and if pointer reach the end of directory, it will return false.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan: Ah ok, i suspected something like that. Wondering why german php-manual doesn't mention it. It semms to be too obvious. The more i thank you for your impulse. Seems similar to the construct of fetch in context of mysqli, which was also magic for me.

Comment: @Franz Thank you. I have three beginner books in front of me and they don't close the bridge from beginners example to "internal pointers" and read the manual. Sorry if I went out of topic, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) `readdir` does:

> Returns the name of the next entry in the directory. The entries are returned in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem.

So everytime you call `readdir` will return the next file from that directory.

For example if you have a direcotry with 2 files:

- `one.txt`
- `two.txt`

First time you call `readdir` will return `one.txt`. And this is different from `false` so will execute the code inside the `while`

Second time you call `readdir` will return `two.txt` and the same as above.

Thrid time you call `readdir` will return `false` because no more files are in that dirrecotry. and the condition from `while` will not be true anymore so will not enter while anymore.

Comment: Thank You! Although I read the manual, I wasn't able to go over that bridge. Now that you give me the context it's plausible.  I was confronted with similar concept several times. Now it seems that you bring me much closer to the point.